# Sonar Scanner null pointer error while run sonar-scanner.bat file

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am getting null pointer exception after executing sonar-scanner.bat file in windows terminal for java mutliple  application. I added path in sonar-scanner

> INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE INFO:
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ INFO: Total time: 25.283s INFO: Final Memory: 15M/57M INFO:
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at org.sonarsource.scm.git.GitScmProviderBefore77.revisionId(GitScmProviderBefore77.java:173)
> at org.sonar.scanner.scm.ScmRevisionImpl.get(ScmRevisionImpl.java:62)
> at org.sonar.scanner.report.MetadataPublisher.addScmInformation(MetadataPublisher.java:153)
> at org.sonar.scanner.report.MetadataPublisher.publish(MetadataPublisher.java:105)
> at org.sonar.scanner.report.ReportPublisher.generateReportFile(ReportPublisher.java:152)
> at org.sonar.scanner.report.ReportPublisher.execute(ReportPublisher.java:138)
> at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:366)
> at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
> at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
> at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:141)
> at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
> at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
> at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:73)
> at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
> at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
> at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
> at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
> at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:126)
> at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:81)
> at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:62) ERROR: ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug
> logging.

I am using below given version of sonarqube and sonarscanner.
sonarqube-7.8
sonar-scanner-cli-4.8.0.2856-windows

I  am trying to get the testing report for my application in SonarQube(localhost :9000).

Any help is appreciated, and if there is more information needed I will  provide it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The scanner fails if it can’t find a HEAD reference when running a scan with git. Can you try commit something and try this again? Alternatively, if there is no HEAD, just specify -Dsonar.scm.disabled=true.

Source: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/nullpointerexception-when-running-scan/15598/4

Comment: I have no idea about HEAD reference and I am trying to test by using sonarqube locally before pushing in git. I am adding Dsonar. scm.disabled=true inside sonar-scanner.properties file.Could u provide us with more references or an easy way  for running properly in local